# Encoding problems in Firefox

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I'm having some big problems with encoding in Firefox when using AJAX and jQuery.
I pass a string with `$.ajax()`, and in the php code I'm using the function:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1",true);
```

jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'Filme_comparador_horarios.php',
    data: 'cartaz='+$filme_compara,
    success: function(retorno)
    {
        $('#cartaz_comp').append(retorno);
    }
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_GET["cartaz"]))
{
    $cartaz = $_GET["cartaz"];      
    echo"
        <div class='cartaz_comp_img'><img class='cartaz_comp_imagem' src='horarios/$cartaz/filme.jpg' width='140px' height='210px'/>
        <div class='nome_comp'>$cartaz</div>
        </div>
        ";
}
```

I already tried using:

```
echo utf8_decode($cartaz);
```

making it run ok in Firefox, but breaking in IE and Chrome.

Comment: Try to see if there's any HTML meta tag altering charset.  e.g. `<meta charset="UTF-8"/>`

Comment: The main php fille has the meta
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" />

Comment: @Renan_Lopes_Ferreira What do you get if you try to access the API directly which is normally accessed with AJAX?

Comment: directly the string is presented in the right way!
The problem is with jquery passing the variable!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with htmlspecialchars in PHP, you can use the code below,

```
echo htmlspecialchars("
    <div class='cartaz_comp_img'><img class='cartaz_comp_imagem' src='horarios/$cartaz/filme.jpg' width='140px' height='210px'/>
    <div class='nome_comp'>$cartaz</div>
    </div>
    ");
```

and in your Ajax page create this javascript function

```
function htmlspecialcharsDecode(specialChars) {
    specialChars = specialChars.replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
      .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
   .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
  .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
  .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");

   return specialChars;
}
```

in your ajax code

```
    success: function(retorno)
{
    $('#cartaz_comp').append(htmlspecialcharsDecode(retorno));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'Filme_comparador_horarios.php',
    data: 'cartaz='+$filme_compara,
    contentType: 'text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1',
    success: function(retorno)
    {
        $('#cartaz_comp').append(retorno);
    }
```

Comment: Nothing really happend!
Example:
the string "Redenção"
output "RedenÃ§Ã£o"

Comment: What's the encoding of the server-side file? (should be the same). Anyway, UTF-8 is a good and recommended practice.

Comment: everything is in ISO-8859-1!
The strange thing is that even when I detect that the browser is Firefox, and use the utf8_decode, when passing to the src="", the string is still wrong

Comment: It can also be a cache problem, which would still display the wrong data even after making those changes (sometimes it happens)